# ios measure tape custom control

Tags: iphone, ios, uicontrol

I want to build measuring tape custom control. It should be like one used in [Weightbot application](http://inspiredm.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/weightbot.png).

Measuring tape is shown only partial on the screen, an by dragging you can pick from 0cm up to 1km.

One way i though of how to do it is to place a very long image in sliding UIImageView, but i sense there is a better way.

Any ideas how to implement this other than static image?

Answer (score 1):

The weightbot application you link to looks like it uses a custom view.

You could use a combination of an image (for the gradation) and custom drawing for the numbers. You don't have to use a single long image that scrolls.

Comment: Thanks for so prompt answer! I taught about your idea, and is this the way to go: say we start from 0cm, and i draw initial screen and one segment to the right (that is not shown on the screen). So now if user drags it to the right i animate already drawn segment and draw next one to the right. Should i delete stuff from the left (wich is not visible any more), or let it be? I am concerned about two things: memory usage of segments drawn but not shown on screen and would the draw/animate action give a smooth behaviour when moving tape left/right.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect use of a `UICollectionView`, if you can target iOS 6 or newer. It does the cell reuse you mention in your comment, but it supports sideways scrolling, which table views don’t. You can do custom drawing for each cell, which might mean you don’t need images at all, or else you can combine a simple repeating image with some dynamic text.